# Search JSON encoded text in MySQL database using LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am trying to fix a bug in our system but I am not sure how to do it.

The software program saves a json encoded text in the database.
The saved encoded text looks like this.

```
{"en":"\u57fa\u672c\u7684\u306a\u8105\u5a01\u4fdd\u8b77"}
```

When I try to search the database using a `LIKE` query it does not return a result.

Following is my query:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Question p WHERE p.deletedAt IS NULL AND p.title LIKE %\u57fa\u672c% AND p.questionType=3;
```

This query works perfectly if I use only one character. As an example if I use only `\u57fa` or `\u672c` it works perfectly. But combinations doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea why it is happening?

Comment: May be you need to separate each by ```OR```? Example:  ```LIKE %\u57fa% OR  LIKE %\u672c%```

Comment: Note that `\u...` in strings are not really "there", they're just escape sequences for unicode. Check your actual table's record and see what MySQL put in it, because there's every chance that it saved this as `{ "en": "基本的な脅威保護" }` instead, since depending on MySQL's charset, that's the exact same string data.

Comment: For one, you need to enclose the text in single quotes. For two, you might have to escape those backslashes.

Comment: @Sammitch that would turn it into "this is no longer JSON". The text shown up top is correct, well-formatted JSON, just with escaped unicode sequences instead of unicode "letters".

Comment: can you provide a full [mre] i am not getting whgat doesn't work  AND means that all conditions have to be met so you need a row where deletedAt  is NULL and the strig must be found and and and. so show us the data and which rows xou want selected

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sure. the JSON is valid, but that's not the point. In order to have a literal backslash inside a Mysql string you need to escape it in the query text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sammitch suggested, escaping the backslashes worked like a charm.

This query worked.

```
SELECT p.* FROM Question p WHERE p.deletedAt IS NULL AND p.title LIKE %\\u57fa\\u672c% AND p.questionType=3;
```